# Can I add [XmlElement] attribute to List members without breaking backwards compatability?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I believe the following:

```
public List<Vector3> Vectors;
```

Will serialize out to:

```
<Vectors>
 <Vector3>
  <X>0</X>
  <Y>0</Y>
  <Z>0</Z>
 </Vector3>
</Vectors>
```

I want to remove the  encasing tag which I believe I can do like this:

```
[XmlElement("Vector3")]
public List<Vector3> Vectors;
```

Which should serialize to:

```
 <Vector3>
  <X>0</X>
  <Y>0</Y>
  <Z>0</Z>
 </Vector3>
```

But I'm afraid that would break old XML files that are still using the "Vectors" tag around the list.  Is there a common way to solve this?

EDIT:  The list above would be part of a container object, so the full XML might begin with

```
<Container>
```

and end with

```
</Container>
```

I left that out originally to keep the question shorter.

Comment: Besides the backward compatibility, how do you expect single Vecotr3 element to represent something like List<T> that inherently is multi-value structure? How would you represent Vectors that has more than 1 element in XML with single XMLElement?

Comment: If there are multiple elements then each element will appear as <Vector3>values</Vector3> <Vector3>values</Vector3> and the order they are specified in the XML is the order they will appear in the list when deserialized - I believe that's fairly standard XML practice.

Comment: <Vector3>values</Vector3> <Vector3>values</Vector3> is not a valid XML. XML has to have a single root element and that is why <Vectors><Vector3>values</Vector3> <Vector3>values</Vector3></Vectors> is used.

Comment: I wasn't explicit about this, but I meant to imply that the List<Vector3> is part of an object, and the entire object will be serialized.  Therefore, the XML would actually be something like <ContainerObject><Vector3>values</Vector3> <Vector3>values</Vector3></ContainerObject>  This is how container objects such as Windows in XAML list their elements (like Buttons and TextBoxes).  They do not surround those with a <Children> tag.

Comment: Your XmlElement decoration should work to remove the Vectors container. But I'm not sure I'm not sure what you're trying to solve. You wrote that you didn't want to break old xml files. If you are worried about backward compatibility why are you breaking it?

Comment: When the file format was originally created it was intended to be an XML file generated only by a single app, and never touched by people.  The app that generates the file has become more popular lately and we're encouraging other apps to generate the XML file - and also users to even edit the file by hand.  I'm using XAML as a model which allows contained elements to exist without tags for the list (as I mentioned a few comments above).  So I'd like to strip out the list tags to make it easier for users to hand-edit the files, but I want old files to still be readable.  Lots of constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe XML has any sort of built in mechanism for versioning. I think your best bet is going to be writing some external mechanism which can detect the "version" as defined by you and deserialize the old version into your new object manually. You probably will also want to define a new version member variable or property which will serialize with your object in case you run into the same problem again, because once you change the schema a 2nd time, you will have 3 versions to worry about.

You can either write a custom deserialize method by defining IXmlSerializable on your object and defining the readXml/writeXml functions, or you can use some external process to generate the new XML format based on the old version. Perhaps load the XML file into an XmlDocument first, fix it how you want (i.e. move the Vector3 nodes up a level and remove the Vectors node), then save the document's OuterXml value into a string and deserialize via a MemoryStream.